# MVC Ajax GET method with JSON object as parameter

Tags: json, ajax, model-view-controller, getmethod

I'm trying to make an Ajax request to an action sending a Json object as parameter.

Here is the code of the Jquery:

```js
var jsonObject = {
    "Id": 33,
    "Name": "TEST"
};

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: rootPath + "ScheduledEvents/Edit/",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    /*contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",*/
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#defaultModalRightEventContent").html(data);
        $("#defaultModalRightEvent").modal("show");
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Here is the class on the server side:

```
public class TestingClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(TestingClass testingClass)
{
    return PartialView("_ScheduledEvent", new ScheduledEventVM());
}
```

What is happening is that even though the object isn't null when hitting the action, both Id and Name as empty.

If I change the method from GET to POST then the object arrives correctly to the action, but then I get a RequiredValidationToken error. And since I don't actually have a form with the token to use I'm really out of options.

Is there a way to use GET or do I really need to use POST.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Its just `data: jsonObject,` (no `.stringify()`) And it needs to be `dataType: "html",` (not `json`) since your returning a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method reads `Edit`, it means it is changing the state of the server. Hopefully an update operation in the database.
As far as `RequiredValidation Token` error is concerned, I think you are talking about `AntiForgeryToken`. You can avoid this by removing `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on your post requests or you can provide the same token from client side using a helper method.
If you write `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your views, it will create a hidden field on in html with name `__RequestVerificationToken`. You can pick up this value and also push this along with ajax request's data and header. After doing this, your problem will go away.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had to go with POST method for this.